# Variable not reseting during FOREACH loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I've written the following code to calculate distance between a query and a set of attributes. However the product attributes are returning the same for every loop, when in fact I know that they're not. Could it be something to do with the wpdb variable?

I've tried resetting the variables to 0 at the top of the loop, and have also tried unset. The code will be working correctly when there is a difference between the distance value for multiple products.

Please see the code below:

```
      $the_query = get_posts( 'cat=2&post_type=product&fields=ids' );
    if($the_query){
        foreach($the_query as $id) {
                //reset variables at begining of foreach loop
                $distance = 0;
                $product_head_standard = 0;
                $product_loft = 0;
                $product_shape = 0;
                $product_trajectory_head_design = 0;
                //queries for product attributes
                $product_head_standard = $wpdb->query("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE meta_key = 'head_standard' AND post_id =".$id);
                $product_shape = $wpdb->query("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE meta_key = 'shape' AND post_id =".$id);
                $product_trajectory_head_design = $wpdb->query("SELECT meta_value 
FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'trajectory_head_design' AND post_id =".$id);
                $product_loft = $wpdb->query("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE meta_key = 'loft' AND post_id =".$id);
                echo $product_head_standard."productheadstandard";
                echo $product_loft."productloft";
                echo $product_shape."shape";
                echo $product_trajectory_head_design."producttracjectory";
                //calculate total height
                $height_variables = $product_trajectory_head_design + $product_loft;
                //calculate difference between search query and product attributes
                $distance = ABS($form_standard-$product_head_standard)
 + ABS($form_desired_shape-$product_shape) + ABS($form_desired_height-$height_variables);
                //output
                echo "<tr><p>id".$id."      distance".$distance."</p></tr>";
```

Comment: It's hard to see why from what you posted. Maybe try echo-ing the numbers whose sum is $distance and make sure that the products in the database really have different data...

Comment: Ok I echoed it and it returns exactly the same results for both IDs.

Comment: 1productheadstandard1productloft0shape1producttracjectory
id95 distance5

1productheadstandard1productloft0shape1producttracjectory
id91 distance5

Comment: Please provide better formatted code and explain the concept of the code. E.g., no one wants to scroll to the right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe single values must be selected using get_var, like this

```
$value = $wpdb->get_var("sql goes here");
```

I believe the numbers you are getting are something other than the value you are looking for. Maybe the number of results.